# How to read line in CLIPS?

Tags: expert-system, clips

I need to read a string in CLIPS so i'm usign (readline) but it doesn't seem to work.
It doesn't let me enter anything and it just returns "". Any ideea what's the issue?

```
CLIPS> (readline)
""
```

I'm using latest version of http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was just a bog on that version i was using.
It seems that the bug was present only in the Windows version, that with a GUI.
If you run it with the one frm command prompt it worked fine.
I reported the bug on their google group, they confirmed and i think it is fixed by now.

Answer (score -1):

Check `(readln)`...

Good luck!